# surround plug-in within global command

Tags: plugin-vim-surround, global-command

I've been unable to use surround within a global command, For example:
`g/^/ norm! yss"` seems to do nothing or replaces the entire line by the contents of the clipboard.

This is consistent with experience reported on github (https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround/issues/161). That report includes no solution.

I'm running gvim 8.0 under Windows 10. Is anyone able to run surround within a global command? If so, what am I missing? If not, is anyone able to explain the limitation?

**Update**: In view of comments received, I must conclude that the problem has to do with my configuration. For the record, I've upgraded to 8.1.1 but that hasn't helped. It seems that it's only the yss commands that fail under global (and those not consistently). ds and cs appear to work. yss works very occasionally (though I've been unable to establish a repeatable circumstance). Otherwise, sometimes the contents of the clipboard are inserted, sometimes there is no change: I cannot yet predict which.

Comment: Instead of `norm!` use `norm` without the exclamation mark

Comment: `:h :norm` says `If the [!] is given, mappings will not be used.`

Comment: @Christian: Sorry, I shouldn't have included the !. Removing it makes no difference. Are you saying the command without ! works for you?

Comment: @justerman Yup after removing the `!`  your command works on my setup.

Comment: @justerman It cannot work for me, because I do not use surround. However it should and I see no reason, why the mapping should not work in a global context.

Comment: I have to admit that I use vim-sandwich with vim-surround mappings. So I can only confirm that it works with vim-sandwich.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for responding. Your comments have been helpful. I've added an update, which states my problem more precisely.

Comment: In case anyone's interested, this morning I wrote a few lines and tried a few command combinations. Eventually, for reasons that escape me, yss began to work consistently. I saved the data as a new file, closed and re-opened it. yss no longer worked.